# An Object is moving but its velocity is 0

Tags: c#, unity, rigid-body-dynamics

In Unity 5 I have an object move when I press a button, force is added as seen by the code below. Then once this force is added I print out its velocity. The problem is that in the console my first print out with the first button press is "velocity(0.0,0.0)" then the second button press gives the printout "velocity(2.0,0.0)". Why is it that i get a velocity of 0 on the first button press even though my object is moving on the screen?

```
if (isPressed == true) {
            moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (100, 0));

            Debug.Log ("velocity" + moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity);

            isPressed = false;
        }
```

Edit **Incase anyone else asks, the code is within a FixedUpdate Method

Comment: Try putting this code in FixedUpdate() instead of Update().  More than likely, you are just playing catch-up with your physics engine.

Comment: @Jon this code is already within FixedUpdate :( would it still be trying to catchup?

Comment: Yeah, I am re-reading what I posted, and I regardless I would be wrong here.  My guess is, that the physics engine calculates all the forces applied, and then updates its velocity at each tick (which is probably done in the background out of your control, after the FixedUpdate() is called).  The documentation doesn't really specify how the behaviour works, therefore, I would assume this is how it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing its velocity using the `AddForce` method. This adds a *force*, not a *velocity* to the body. The change of velocity happens the next time the rigidbody physics are processed by the game engine, which happens during the next FixedUpdate.

Comment: thanks for this! had a suspicion it was something like that, ty!